# Yii r1.8 Using Custom URL Rule Classes

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to take advantage of the [Custom URL Rule Classes](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/docs/guide/topics.url.txt#342) in Yii r1.8

I am trying to take something that looks like orgs/view/id/24 and instead display the name of the org as identified by Name in the db (i.e. changing www.mysite.com/orgs/view/id/24 to www.mysite.com/jaysshop dynamically ).  Unfortunately I am not getting it to work.

Here is my code:

```
class OrgsUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule
{
    public $connectionID = 'db';

    public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand)
    {
        if ($route==='orgs/view/id')  //even tried 'orgs/view' or 'orgs/index'
        {
            if (isset($params['Name']))
                return $params['Name'];
            else if (isset($params['Name']))
                return $params['Name'];
        }
        return false;  
    }

    public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo)
    {
        if (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches))
        {
        }
        return false;  
    }
}
```

urlManager:

```
array(
  'class' => 'application.components.OrgsUrlRule',
  'connectionID' => 'db',
),
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do here. Is a customer typing the orgs/view/id/24 url and you want to redirect him to jaysshop? Or are you trying to make urls from within your code to display? I think you might have the wrong idea about the createUrl function. That one is used when you use the createUrl functionality somewhere in your site. If you want to actually take a pageview and want to "translate" the url then you need the parseUrl function instead.

Comment: @Blizz I understand what you are saying, but with this new functionality in Yii r1.8 (linked above) it is showing urlManager handling the url rewrites.  Just as you can use, in urlManger, 'events'=>'events/index' to have users type www.mysite.com/events instead of www.mysite.com/events/index.  As I read it Custom URL Rule Classes should allow you to do the same thing on a more widespread but granular scale.

Comment: @Blizz In this forum question, [Need of URL with username, similar to facebook](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10829-need-of-url-with-username-similar-to-facebook/) they figured out what I want to do with a variable but that is far before the release of the added functionality in Yii r1.8 that I am trying to understand and use

Comment: Enfield i'm not claiming otherwise. CBaseUrlRule is indeed used to modify the incoming and outgoing urls. But you appear to be using its functions wrong. When the site is about to get loaded, the "parseUrl" function is called to process the url into a controller/action. The createUrl function is only called when you, from inside your code, want to output a link.

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving you this example in the assumption that you want to take the name of a shop from the URL trigger the your controller/action on it

For example:

```
public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo)
{
   $aParts = explode('/', $pathInfo);
   if (count($aParts) == 1) // It's only 1 piece, so a possible "shop name"
   {
      if (isAValidNameForAShop($aParts[0]))
      {
         $_REQUEST['id'] = $aParts[0]; // Store it to retrieve it in the controller
         return 'orgs/view';
      }
   }
   return FALSE; // Seems like something else, we don't apply
 }
```

Hope that helps you along a bit.

Comment: @ Blizz, thanks for the input.  I will try and incorporate this tomorrow.